# TypeError error when submit button is clicked

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I am using bootstrap in my django webapp. I have the following `base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Kevin's Blog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'blog/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'blog/css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                {% if user.is_active %}
                    <span class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'login' %}" style="font-size: 15px">{{user.username}}</span>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/logout/" style="font-size: 15px">log out</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'login' %}" style="font-size: 15px">Login</a>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'register' %}" style="font-size: 15px">Signup</a>
                {% endif %}


            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'post' %}">Post</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'project' %}">Project</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

        <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/wz246">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/hitzhuwen">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://github.com/spoiledPiggy">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="copyright text-muted">Copyright &copy; Kevin's Website 2015</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'blog/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="{% static 'blog/js/clean-blog.min.js' %}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I want to create a login page (extends the `base.html`)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container"> 

<div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
    <div class="panel panel-info" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
            </div>     

            <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                <form action="/auth/" id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">                                        
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                              <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" value="login" />
                              <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                    Don't have an account! 
                                <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                    Sign Up Here
                                </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </form>     

                </div>                     
            </div>  
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The `login` submit button doesn't work, but if I remove the `base.html`(I will lose the CSS...), then it will be fine. Can anyone help with that?

When I clicked the submit button, there's an error in the console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of
>   undefined$.jqBootstrapValidation.submitSuccess @
>   clean-blog.min.js:7(anonymous function) @
>   clean-blog.min.js:7jQuery.event.dispatch @
>   jquery.js:4409elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4095

Comment: Can you tell me what errors if any you get inside of the developer tools console of your browser?  You can access it by right clicking on the page when it is loaded and click on the inspect element option and then click on the console tab.  Then click on your submit button and see if shows any errors.

Comment: If you have a live link to the site I might be able to give you hand in sorting out the problem.

Comment: I would also check what path the button is submitting to by using the net tab inside of the developer console. It will show up in red if the path is incorrect.  To test it just click on the submit button and observe what address it tries to reach.

Comment: @LarryLane Thanks Larry, I haven't deployed the website so I can't give you the link. But I did get some errors in the console, it seems related the js files. I updated the errors in the question I posted.

Comment: is cleanblog.js a library of yours? if so can you let me know what the line in it around line 7 is using an indexOf function call.  It appears as if it the value passed to it is probably null.

Comment: Ok I believe I found line that is returning the errror This code is from the github page for cleanblog.js and it appears the error is derrived from the following code:   if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }

Comment: I would start by commenting out the script tag that loads the cleanblog.js file. If it still doesn't work then you know it is not the cleanblog.js file exclusely. Then you can move on to checking other components. Good luck let me know if you find anything out.

Comment: thanks, I commented the script and it worked fine.